# CygWin doesn't recognize Package Manager (?)

Tags: cygwin

I have installed WinZip and 7Zip, but still the problem occurs

[image: Screenshot of error]

It says...

```
Now attempting installation... 
Looking for a previous installation of SDKMAN... 
Looking for unzip... 
Not found. 
====================================================================================================== 
Please install unzip on your system using your favourite package manager. 

Restart after installing unzip. 
======================================================================================================
```

Comment: WinZip most definitely isn’t a Cygwin application.  I suspect you also installed a Windows version of 7Zip.  Have you tried installing an appropriate solution from within Cygwin. Make sure you [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary without any formatting that cannot be reasonably deciphered. Commentary containing information that should be in your question body will be flagged.

Comment: I would save yourself the trouble with Cygwin and install WSL1 before you go much further.  WSL allows the installation of *real* Linux distros and WSL1 (specifically) is easier to manage for a beginner.  You can install any Linux apps you want and follow Linux instructions and get Linux gurus to help when it goes wrong.  Cygwin is a fairly bloated port and (IMHO) no longer provides much value on a windows platform.  Just my two cents.

Comment: You did not write what command you typed to get the error messages. Are you sure that what you are going to install will work in a Cygwin environment? Also, please install the Cygwin versions of unzip it in your Cygwin scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The message is very clear

> Please install unzip on your system

In which Cygwin package is unzip ?

```
$ cygcheck -p bin/unzip
Found 13 matches for bin/unzip
busybox-1.23.2-1 - busybox: Tiny utilities in a single executable (installed binaries and support files)
...
unzip-6.0-15 - unzip: Info-ZIP decompression utility (installed binaries and support files)
unzip-6.0-16 - unzip: Info-ZIP decompression utility
unzip-6.0-17 - unzip: Info-ZIP decompression utility
...
zziplib-0.13.67-1 - zziplib: ZIP file utilities
zziplib-0.13.68-1 - zziplib: ZIP file utilities
zziplib-0.13.71-1 - zziplib: ZIP file utilities
```

I would say `unzip` is the likely candidate.
After installing `unzip` with Cygwin setup you will have

```
$ cygcheck -l unzip
/usr/bin/funzip.exe
/usr/bin/unzip.exe
/usr/bin/unzipsfx.exe
/usr/bin/zipgrep
/usr/bin/zipinfo
/usr/share/...

$ unzip --help
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.
....
```